# java.net.SocketTimeoutException error while web-scraping

Tags: java, sockets, download, web-scraping, sourceforge

I am currently working on a program that scrapes through sourceforge.com and retrieves links of tarballs from the repositories of open source projects written in java.

I initially fire an empty search command in the home page, this lists down projects in sourceforge.net with filters in the left side. I then filter by "java" programming language and then browse through each category (total 10 categories of projects) and retrieve links of the first 25 projects in each category. Thus, now i have a Hashmap having 250 project names and its web address.
Moving further, I go into each of these links and get the "Browse Code" link in each of its pages. This page has the link for the "Download TARball".

While I am trying to connect to different pages and move deeper from the home page, I get the following error at runtime (the error occurs randomly during execution time)

Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)

I tried to give a 3minute wait time between each "Jsoup.connect" request. But still the error persists.
I am not sure why this occurs and how to solve this. Any suggestions, ideas are most welcome.

A sample flow of links is provided below :
1. HomePage 
2. Empty Search fired
3. Filter by Java and Mobile category
4. First project after filtering
5. Browse Link in the Project : http://wurfl.cvs.sourceforge.net/wurfl/
6. Final Tarball Link : http://wurfl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/wurfl/?view=tar

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure why this occurs and how to solve this. Any suggestions, ideas are most welcome.

Two possibilities:

- The servers are temporarily overloaded, broken, whatever.
- The servers are implementing some kind of technical means to try to *prevent* you web scraping.

Have you checked that what you are trying to do complies with the [SourceForge Terms of Service](https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sitelegal/wiki/Terms_of_Use)?

Comment: @Stephen... Thank you so much for the prompt reply.. I went through the "Terms" given in sourceforge.net and it doesn't really specify anything against web-scraping. Wrt this ERROR, i looked more into issues related to web scraping on stackoverflow and came to know that "Connection and network problems could result in such problems. To avoid blocking scraping of other urls you could parallelize the work into separate threads."
I don't really know much about threading in java. Any ideas if this could help with this problem ? Worth a try ?

Comment: Parallelizing is likely to increase load on the StackOverflow servers and make the problem worse.  I would also draw your attention to "Prohibited Usage" items d) and e).  It sounds like you could be violating d).

Comment: Another suggestion - ask the SourceForge guys for advice via their normal support channels.

Comment: @Stephen... Ya.. Paralleling increases the load.. And ya.. I have mailed the sourceforge ppl to know if wht i wish to do is permitted.Thnx again..